# Input redirection - if open file for write failed

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal

I implement a simple shell in linux (c language).
I checked in the terminal this line: `./myprogram < a.txt` when I haven't any permissions to  `a.txt`.  That such the `myprogram` was run with empty file. The quesion: how can I send empty file after `open()` failed?

Example code:

```
if( fork() == 0 ){
  int f_in = open("a.txt", O_RDONLY);
  if(f_in == -1){
    perror("open input");
    f_in = ???
}
  dup2(f_in, STDIN_FILENO);
  execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

The new program's stdin should be empty, only EOF.

Comment: not sure if I understand. Do you mean to redirect to STDOUT?

Comment: Perhaps I am also confused.  The content of a.txt can be read without a call to open by reading STDIN.  What file are you attempting to open?  Perhaps you can share some code?

Comment: @liangricha
@MahonriMoriancumer
`myprogram` in not my shell. It's some else.
I am adding some code

Comment: If an input redirection fails, you *don't* want to produce an error??

Comment: @glennjackman
I want the behavior similar to the ubuntu's terminal.
Produce an error, but even though run the program, with empty stdin.

Comment: bash does not work that way: `( echo foo; cat - ) < no.such.file` will not echo "foo"

Comment: @glennjackman
You're right. The case that I want to handle is pipe case: `echo foo < a.txt | echo foo`, and what I need is similar to what I wrote about the input redirection. I will edit it.

Comment: `echo` does not read from standard input, and the two sides of a pipe operate independently, other than the RHS reading from the output of the LHS. In neither case does a command default to an empty input file if the open fails.

Comment: The how about `f_in = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);`

Answer (score 0):

Here you may open file in read/write mode if file is available then you will get f_in from open with data available in file and if file is not available then file will be created which is only having EOF and you will give that f_in to proceed further.
May it helps you.
Example:

```
if( fork() == 0 ){
   int f_in = open("a.txt", O_RDWR);
   if(f_in == -1){
      perror("open input");
   }
   dup2(f_in, STDIN_FILENO);
   execvp(args[0], args);
}
```